# Bubble sort in c programming

Tags: arrays, c, bubble-sort

I am a beginner c programmer. I was trying to make a program which will return the highest value of an array. For that you should first sort the array. And for sorting the array I used Bubble sort method, and after doing bubble sort my plan was to return the first element of the sorted array. So that it will return the highest value of the array. But the moment I run the code It is printing garbage values. Here is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int bub(int arr[]);

int main(){

//creating an array
int arr[] = {23,4,65,76,87};

/*calling the function. Here I am printing it. because when I just call the function it is not 
returning anything*/ 

int abs = bub(arr);
printf("%d",abs);
}

// defining function
int bub(int arr[]){

// creating a loop to go till the end of the array
for (int i = 0 , len = sizeof(arr[i]) / sizeof(int) ; i<len ; i++){
    for (int j = 0;j<i;j++){
  
        // swaping if the the value is greater than the next value of the array
        if (arr[j]>arr[j+1]){
        // swaping the values 
        arr[j] = arr[j]^arr[j+1];
    
        arr[j+1] = arr[j]^arr[j+1];
    
        arr[j] = arr[j]^arr[j+1];

        // printing the first value to get the highest value
        printf("%d",arr[0]);
      }

    }
  }
}
```

why is it return printing garbage values? Is there any better way to find the highest value of an array?. Or is there anything that I can improve in this code?

please reply.

Comment: Turn up/on warnings. The `bub` function is not returning anything.

Comment: Do basic debugging. Step thru the code in a debugger. `len =  sizeof(arr[i]) / sizeof(int)` For starters, check `len`. Is it what you expect it to be?

Comment: I tried debugging. I did not understood what was wrong. anyway I got the answer

Answer (score 0):

If you to use bubble sort to find highest value, below is the program I have modified. Note that you are using '>' to compare in such case the first element will be lowest , I changed it and it is better to declare the size of array in main function and pass it to functions as a parameter where you want to use it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int bub(int arr[], int n);

int main(){

//creating an array
int arr[] = {23,4,65,76,87};
int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int);
int abs = bub(arr, n);
printf("\n%d",abs);

}

// defining function
int bub(int arr[], int n){
// creating a loop to go till the end of the array

for (int i = 0; i<n-1 ; i++){
    for (int j = 0;j<n-i-1;j++){
  
        // swaping if the the value is greater than the next value of the array
        if (arr[j] < arr[j+1]){
        // swaping the values 
       // int t = arr[j]; arr[j]=arr[j+1]; arr[j+1]=t;
        arr[j] = arr[j]^arr[j+1];
    
        arr[j+1] = arr[j]^arr[j+1];
    
        arr[j] = arr[j]^arr[j+1];

        // printing the first value to get the highest value
        //printf("%d",arr[0]);
      }
    }
  }
  
  return arr[0];
}
```

Another simpler way is to just traverse through the array once to find highest or lowest value.
Like this

```
int highest = arr[0];
for (int i = 1; i<n ; i++){
    if(arr[i] > highest) highest = arr[i];
  }
printf("%d", highest);
```

Comment: Bro It is not working. It is not sorted. It is returning 65 instead of 87. I tried printing the array, Then I understood that it is no sorted. Anyway Thank U For replying. Hoping a reply about how to solve this bug.

Comment: It has been updated, check it

Comment: Yes. It is working. Thank U so much

Comment: Could You explain what you did in the for loop.

Comment: It's the bubble sort, for every iteration of "i" the smallest value (since we are using > operator) moves to the last index of array( think of it moving like a bubble to one end hence the name bubble sort). The inner loop is responsible for finding the smallest element and moving to its appropriate position by swapping. Then we increase value of "i" since the length of unsorted array now reduces.

Comment: Okay. i understood. Thank U